# How to use Observables, RxJava and Android to access a Webapi?

Tags: android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, rx-java, retrofit2

I am trying to use RxJava to chain a list of requests but I can't figure out how to do it correctly.
I have a list (LIST_A), that I want to iterate through and send its data to the first service (SERVICE_A). As soon as I get the response I have to send a new list (LIST_B) to a second web service (SERVICE_B).
Flow:
-> LOOP (LIST_A)
  SEND ITEM_A ->> 
      AFTER SENDING THIS ITEM_A (it needs to start the second LOOP (LIST_B) and send all the items)
-- END LOOP

That is what I have done so far:

```
private static <T> Observable<T> makeObservable(final Callable<T> func) {
    return Observable.create(
            new Observable.OnSubscribe<T>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Subscriber<? super T> subscriber) {
                    try {
                        subscriber.onNext(func.call());
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        Log.e("OP_DAO", "Error reading from the database", ex);
                    }
                }
            });
}

public Observable<List<VisitInfo>> getVisitObservable() {
    return makeObservable(this.getVisit())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) ;
}

public Callable<List<VisitInfo>> getVisit() {
    return new Callable<List<PesquisaInfo>>() {
        @Override
        public List<VisitInfo> call() throws Exception {
            List<VisitInfo> list = new ArrayList<VisitInfo>();

            // 1. build the query
            String query = "SELECT * FROM "
                    + VISIT ;
            // 2. get reference to writable DB

            try {
                Cursor cursor = getMyWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
                // 3. go over each row, build book and add it to list
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        VisitInfo v = new VisitInfo();
                        ...
                        list.add(v);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    closeCursor(cursor);
                }
                return list;
            } finally {
                closeDatabase();
            }
        }
    };

}

Client client = new ServiceGenerator().createService(Client.class);
Call<List<WS01>> wsServiceCall = client.GetData(user);
Call<List<WS02>> wsService2Call = client.GetData2(dependent of first call);
```

Anyone can help me please, I spent a few days trying to understand how to use RxJava and Retrofit but it is being harder than I expected.

Comment: So, it's not clear what you want to do; which of the following do you need? `for(A in list_a){clientA.sendA}; for(B in list_B){clientB.sendB};` or `for(A in list_a){clientA.sendA; for(B in list_B){clientB.sendB}; };` ?

Comment: The second option, but it sendB needs to execute only after sendA receive the answer.
Thanks for trying to help Tassos Bassoukos, I really appreciate that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you need to describe your problem better; use a bit of pseudocode or a sequence diagram.

One way to do what you want is approximately as follows:

```
import static Observable.*;

public List<VisitInfo> getVisit() { /* just do the db things here */ }

return defer(() -> from(getVisit()))
      .flatMap(visit ->
          fromCallable(client.getData(visit))
          .flatMapIterable(otherList -> otherList)
          .flatMap(other -> fromCallable(client.getData2(visit, other))));
```

If you use Retrofit, then you don't even need the `fromCallable` calls, just make the interface methods return Observables.